# Converting ICC profiles in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, color-profile, color-management

I have a bunch of png images with embedded icc color profiles. When I load and display them the colors is wrong which I understand is because the color profile information is not taken into account. So what I'm trying to do instead is to convert the pixels in the data to sRGB and discard the profile information from the images. That should display them onscreen with the right colors.

I found a script to do that here: http://hipolabs.com/en/blog/icc-profile-transformation-using-pil/

I adapted it to the following Python script:

```
from PIL.ImageCms import profileToProfile
from PIL import Image
from sys import argv

ADOBE_RGB_PROFILE = "AdobeRGB1998.icc"
SRGB_PROFILE = "sRGB.icc"

def main(src, dst):
    original_image = Image.open(src)
    if 'icc_profile' in original_image.info:
        print "converting..."
        converted_image = profileToProfile(original_image, ADOBE_RGB_PROFILE, SRGB_PROFILE)
        print "saving file..."
        converted_image.save(dst)
        print "ok."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(argv[1], argv[2])
```

But it doesn't work. The resulting image is just left transparent.

So my question is, how do you convert images with embedded color profiles in Python? If you can fix my script, or write a new script that does what the above code intends to do that would be great.

Comment: I think there is a bug in the script you based this on. It says `if 'icc_profile' in original_image.info:`, but then in the comments below is says you should *not* do this when the image already has a profile!